How do I fix the 'Failed to create scan_source' error when trying to use ouster-cli with a specific sensor IP address?
ouster-sdk Version - 0.13.1
Steps Taken
Tried setting locale manually (export LANG=en_US.UTF-8).
Checked sensor’s IP connectivity (no issues).

What is the full command you used and the full error message?
